# Camel .to file extension

Tags: java, apache-camel

In ActiveMQ I browse my que "account". When I click on it I can see that different messages has a message ID, "My-computername-some-numbers" (I think they are set by ActiveMQ).

I want camel to read from the que and write the data into a file named "My-computername-some-numbers.xml". Now my output file is only ".xml".

My code:

```
 from("jms:accounting")
.log("### Read jms:accounting ###")
.to("file:src/main/resources/data/work_in_progress?fileName=${file:name.noext}.xml");
```

Comment: try `${file:name.noext}`

Comment: Tried it. It gave me a file named .xml.

Comment: Could you tell me what's your expected output. I thought you need only filename

Comment: In ActiveMQ I browse my que "account". When I click on it I can see that different messages has a message ID, "My-computername-some-numbers" (I think they are set by ActiveMQ).

I want camel to read from the que and write the data into a file named "My-computername-some-numbers.xml". Now my output file is only ".xml".

Comment: The problem here seems to be that you're reading from a JMS-queue. Thus the message is not being treated as a file and doesn't have a filename. I'm assuming this is why the file:name returns an empty string, rendering your file name as only ".xml".

Comment: Thats correct. And how can I give the JMS-queue a file name?

Comment: I guess a solution will be to use the date ? 
.to("file:src/main/resources/data/work_in_progress?fileName=$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.xml");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the JMS message ID in the file name, then you can use `fileName=${id}.xml`

The `fileName` option supports the simple language syntax which you can use: http://camel.apache.org/simple

For more advanced naming, then either set the `CamelFileName` header with the name you want, or look at using dynamic to. However the latter is less ideal if you have unlimited dynamic values as that creates new endpoints per unique value - which is not so good. Its better to use `fileName` or the `CamelFileName` header.

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html